# Can I transfer UV seams between objects?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a couple of objects. They have the same geometry (duplicates), but different scales.

Can I transfer the UV **seams** between them? Linking them via UV's results in a stretched texture.

I know the obvious solution was to mark the seams before doing the duplicates, but that milk has spilled.

Answer (score 1):

[*Data Transfer modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html) to the rescue:

[image]

In your case, the mapping sounds as if it should be via *Topology*

Comment: awsome! Thank you :)